# Android, how to minus 1 of position of ListView Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, position

I created a listView Adapterwith a custom header.

Now it seems to have included the header as an item of the listView, So if i click on a item 2, it will give me the item 3 and so on.

here my code.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_profile_fragment, container, false);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView");

// Setup Views
productsListView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.productsGridView);
header = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_product_header, null);
productsListView.addHeaderView(header);

coverImage          = (ImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.imageCover);
profileImage        = (BootstrapCircleThumbnail)header.findViewById(R.id.imageProfile);
textViewUserName    = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserName);
textViewUserEmail   = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserEmail);



// Adapter
productsListView.setAdapter(adapter = new ProductsAdapter());
// On Item clicked
productsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onClick of gridview" + position);


        ProductsDataModel data = adapter.getItem(position);

        Fragment mFragment = null;      
        mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        mFragment = new ProductFragment().newInstance("Product Page");

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("product_id", data.product_id);

        mFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        if (mFragment != null){     
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.content_frame, mFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    }//end onItemClick
});//end gridview.setOnItemClickListener
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this.

1.) Subtract 1 from your position:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    ProductsDataModel data = adapter.getItem(position -1);
```

2.) Subtract the number of header views from your position:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    ProductsDataModel data = adapter.getItem(position - productsListView.getHeaderViewsCount());
```

3.) (Probably the best solution) Instead of using your adapter as declared in your fragment, use the (wrapped) adapter that the onItemClick listener passes back to you:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    ProductsDataModel data = ((ProductsAdapter)parent.getAdapter()).getItem(position);
```

Comment: tmalseed, Thanks for your anwser. But If I click on the Header Item then App crash. Do you know how to target the herder click and then load another fragment. ? thanks

Comment: There could be any number of reasons. I think that's a separate question. Don't forget to include your stacktrace so people can help you debug it.

Answer (score 1):

To get item in adapter you can use code below:

```
productsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Object obj=parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if(obj instanceOf ProductsDataModel ){
                ProductsDataModel data=(ProductsDataModel )obj;
                //do your stuff here    
                }
        }//end onItemClick
    });//end gridview.setOnItemClickListener
```